# Firebase Storage - Is there a difference in querying time/performance from getting a reference by its filename vs URL?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

Firebase Storage offers some options to get a reference to a file. Among them, I am considering storing a URL so that I can use some caching library like Picasso, as well as to store files inside the device's internal storage (in case the cache has forgotten the image, better to get it from internal storage while it downloads through Picasso again).

To do that, I am storing the downloadURL in the Firebase Database and in my structures. I am wondering if storing the filename as well, and therefore query by the filename rather than by the url would make the retrieval time/performance faster.

So, which of these would be better/faster:

1)      `FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("filename")`

or

2) `FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://blabla.com")`

I believe the first option would be better, but that depends on how the second option query is structured. Perhaps they are pratically equivalent?

Comment: When retrieving a file, the vast majority of time will be spent retrieving the actual payload. Looking up the reference is going to be minimal compared to that.

Comment: Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen :)